# Issues setting up Virtualenv and Virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, django, bash, virtualenv

I'm trying to install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` so that I can do some django work.

I'm not exactly sure where the issue is stemming from. I currently have installed Jupyter Notebook and installed a lot of python files though it (python 3+ I believe), so when I did `pip install virtualevnwrapper`, the location of the shell file was in `C:/Users/'Andy Renz'/Anaconda3/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh`. I account for this in changing by `.bashrc` file, by including:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source C:/Users/'Andy Renz'/Anaconda3/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

When I run `source ~/.bashrc` in my shell, I get the following:

```
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could no import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for 
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and the PATH is
set properly.
```

I think this means python isn't where it is supposed to be. `Virtualenv` references python 2+ I believe which leads me to believe my python 2 is somewhere odd. I do have it, not downloaded from Jupyter. How do I account for this and proceed forward?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you're trying to install the default virtualenvwrapper (for Linux) on a Windows machine. That's why it's trying to get Python from /usr/bin/python, a directory that does not exist in Windows.

Try virtualenvwrapper-win from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win

Comment: @AndyRenz would you mind marking this post as the 'accepted answer'? It would help other people searching for the same thing find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Python is somehow either not installed or installed at different path maybe `/usr/local/bin`. Use `which python` or `whereis python` to check if python is indeed installed and path of installation. Then you can create a softlink to the python executable in your /usr/bin directory.